# get element by name with wildcard and append id

Tags: jquery, wildcard

I'm trying to modify a CMS via jquery because I don't have access to modify the html directly. The html I'm trying to modify is:

```
<td>
<input 
    class="editabletextinput_smaller" 
    type="text" 
    maxlength="6" 
    style="width: 20px;" 
    value="" 
    name="QtyReturned___67347" 
    onkeyup="ShowSave()" 
    onchange="ShowSave()">
</td>
```

My jquery is:

```
document.ready = function(exchange)
{
    var qtyReturned = $("input[name^='QtyReturned_']");
    qtyReturned.attr("id","exchange_return");
}
```

but it does not work.

The `name` attribute is dynamic so it's never the same, so I want to get the element that has `name="QTYReturned_(whatever the number is)"` and do several things to it, the first of which is to add an `id` so I can `getElementById` and append and so on.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are there multiple inputs with a name starting with `QtyReturned_`?

Comment: `document.ready = function(exchange){` is not valid jQuery.  I think you meant `$(document).ready(function(){})`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/km32y/ ... Works fine just as @RocketHazmat suggest change the expression

Comment: @czarchaic good question, there are in some instances. Is there a way to do an array and give an id for each instance like "exchange_return_1" "exchange_return_2" etc?

Comment: If there is more than 1 item returned from you query, the result is an array(like) object. It has a length property and can be iterated over. What happens when you `console.log(qtyReturned.length)`?

Comment: @czarchaic in this record the console.log(qtyReturned.length) returns 4 because there are 4 items that render the `QtyReturned_ input` element but there could be 1, or 8, or 5, who knows. Any ideas on how I would give a different id (starting with "exchange_return_" to each one?

Comment: @RocketHazmat Hey Rocket, you answered the question as it was asked, if you want to post it as an answer I'll mark it as the answer, thanks! :)